# MapView doesn't work on android

Tags: android, google-maps, api-key

i have this 
manifest file

> ```
>     <permission
>             android:name="com.mine.signedgooglemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
>             android:protectionLevel="signature" />
>
>     <uses-feature
>             android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
>             android:required="true" />
>
>     <uses-permission android:name="com.mine.signedgooglemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
>     <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"
> ```
>
> />

with this activity

```
package com.mine.signedgooglemap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

public class signedgooglemapActivity extends MapActivity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

my main.xml file is

> ```
> <com.google.android.maps.MapView
>         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>         android:id="@+id/mapview"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>         android:clickable="true"
>         android:apiKey="AIzaSyC0WDs0wXDuGwTipv6hDnbnIOObL9oR0Ms"
>         />
> ```

i sign the application with my keystore 
 then i get sha1 fingerprint of my keystore  and let google console generate new api key
 by useing this line
 5B:66:36:BB:AE:44:3B:36:52:2D:88:6F:A3:44:AD:3C:E4:0F:AB:5D;com.mine.signedgooglemap

i get this message in the debugger

> 02-05 10:56:15.228: WARN/System.err(873): IOException processing: 26
>   02-05 10:56:15.228: WARN/System.err(873): java.io.IOException: Server
>   returned: 3 02-05 10:56:15.234: WARN/System.err(873): at
>   android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
>   02-05 10:56:15.248: WARN/System.err(873): at
>   android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
>   02-05 10:56:15.254: WARN/System.err(873): at
>   android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
>   02-05 10:56:15.268: WARN/System.err(873): at
>   android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
>   02-05 10:56:15.274: WARN/System.err(873): at
>   android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
>   02-05 10:56:15.274: WARN/System.err(873): at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)

Comment: WHat is your question? Did you already do a search for a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set up your manifest follow all the specifications listed [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start?hl=en)

Also `MapActivity` is depreciated as shown here. Look into using the [`MapFragment`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment) which is compatible with Google Maps API v 2.

Answer (score 0):

Also include this library into your mainifest:

```
  <uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding the

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

in you manifest file.